# Export the signature for Facebook on android

Tags: android, shell, command-line

I am exporting the signature for my app so that Facebook can use to ensure users are only communicating with my app on the Android. I´m using this command:

keytool -exportcert -alias my alias -keystore /Where/is/my/Keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

I have one question: My alias name has two words and between these two words there is a space. My alias is like this "my alias". To put this command in the terminal I have to put any symbol for this space something like "_" "*"....?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Either wrap the two words of the alias in quotation marks -- e.g. `"my alias"` -- or use backslash to escape the space: `my\ alias`